# Cannot read property 'sdks' of undefined - Appcelerator TiSDK 5.5.1ga

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-modules, titanium-android

Facing the below issue when trying to build Android module using Appcelerator studio 4.8.1 and Titanium SDK 5.5.1 GA, I am getting the below error. Not able to resolve this.

> | ERROR  | An uncaught exception was thrown! Cannot read property
>   'sdks' of undefined | ERROR  | Cannot read property 'sdks' of
>   undefined

Answer (score 0):

Updating the build tools and all seems to have resolved the issue.